# Unsuccessful to use Marionette, the next generation of FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

According to this [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver), there is no FirefoxDriver from Firefox 47, instead we use Marionette.

I followed the instructions in this link, but it doesn't work as expected. I am using Java, Firefox 47 and Mac OSX Capitan

1. I installed selenium driver with this `npm install selenium-webdriver` as suggested in the link
2. I set up the Marionette executable by downloading this file `geckodriver-0.8.0-OSX.gz`, unrar it, and changed the name to `wires` as instructed in the link. And I ensured it is executable with `chmod +x wires`
3. I used Marionette like this, from Mozilla Developer

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

   Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
   ```

But when I run the test, the same exception like this normal FirefoxFriver

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Is anyone successful to use Marionette? Am I missing something from Mozilla's instructions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and just solved it by updating the Selenium version to `2.53.1`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: it sure does help! Thank you very much. Selenium version `2.53.1` fixes the problem